# Issue loading any package in R

Tags: r, mapping, tmap

I have successfully installed the `tmap` package in RStudio version 1.2.1335.

However when I try to load it with the `library(tmap)` command I get this error message:

```
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘tmap’ in dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...):
 unable to load shared object '/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.0/Resources/library/raster/libs/raster.so':
  dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.0/Resources/library/raster/libs/raster.so, 6): Symbol not found: _EXTPTR_PTR
  Referenced from: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.0/Resources/library/raster/libs/raster.so
  Expected in: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/lib/libR.dylib
 in /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.0/Resources/library/raster/libs/raster.so
```

I am having this issue with all packages (newly installed or old), and am unsure where to begin looking for the issue.

Comment: While I don't have a mac, I've seen several questions/answers with problems similar to this, and a common resolution involves updating or (re)installing `xcode` on mac. (`xcode` is an OS package, not an R thing.)

Comment: Thank you r2evans, I actually just reinstalled R and RStudio completely and the issue seems to be resolved. I will edit the question and explain this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved this issue by reinstalling R and RStudio

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you lost the package about 'raster'.
Maybe you go to install it.